# How would I represent the following constraint in the linear form?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

Given the optimization variables $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$ and $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, I would like to represent the following constraint to the linear form

$\mathrm{diag}(\mathbf{|b|})(|\mathbf{a}|-|\mathbf{b}|) = \mathbf{y}$.

Notation: $\mathrm{diag}$ represents diagonal and $|.|$ is an absolute value

Comment: What does $|\mathbf{b}|$ mean? The absolute value or the norm?

Comment: It is absolute value

Comment: Why should this have a linear form? If $z=a+bi$ is a complex number then the constraint $1\leq |z|\leq 2$ is the same as $1 \leq a^2 + b^2 \leq 4$, which is nonconvex over $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Hello Michale,  I agree,  but I am super worried about the constraint and not the bounds.  Thanks for your advice.